# the probability that exactly k envelopes will contain a card with a matching colour

Tags: probability, combinatorics, analysis

> **Suppose that 10 cards, of which seven are red and three
> are green, are put at random into 10 envelopes, of which
> seven are red and three are green, so that each envelope
> contains one card. Determine the probability that exactly
> k envelopes will contain a card with a matching colour
> (k = 0, 1, . . . , 10).**

my attempt:

the number of ways to distribute ten cards on ten envelops is $\frac{10!}{7!3!}$(we assume that the cards in the same colour are indistinguishable)

now for $k=10$:
the only way that each of  $10$ envelopes  will contain a card  with the matching colour is by ensure that each of 7 red envelops will contain a red card and each of the 3 envelops will contain a green card :so the probability in this case is $\frac{1}{\frac{10!}{7!3!}}$

for $k=9$:there is not a way,to clarifies that let's suppose that 6 red envelops will contain the red cards and 3 green envelops will contain the green cards,then it still one red card and the only envelops that it can be placed on is the one with red colour,so we will not get that  exactly $9$ envelopes  will contain a card  with the matching colour

for $k=8$:we should have 6 red envelops with the matching cards and 2 green envelops with matching cards,we can ensure that by choosing 6 red envelops from 7 to put the 6 red cards,and choose 2 envelops from the 3 green envelops to put the one red card that remains,so the probability in this case is $\frac{{7 \choose 6}{3 \choose 1}}{\frac{10!}{7!3!}}$.
.

for $k=7$  :there is not way

for $k=6$  :we should have 5 red envelops with matching cards and 1 green envelops with matching cards,so we need to choose 5 red envelops from 7 to put the 5 red cards,and choose 2 envelops from the 3 green envelops to put the two red card that remains,the probability in this case is $\frac{{7 \choose 5}{3 \choose 2}}{\frac{10!}{7!3!}}$.

for $k=5$ :there is not way

for $k=4$ :we should have 4 red envelops with the matching cards and 0 green envelops with matching cards,so we need to choose 4 red envelops from 7 to put the 4 red cards,and choose 3 envelops from the 3 green envelops to put the 3 red card that remains,the probability in this case is $\frac{{7 \choose 4}{3 \choose 3}}{\frac{10!}{7!3!}}$.

questions:
**-does my approach is right?**

**-can you suggest an easier approach ?**.

Comment: To choose a permutation of $n$ elements with exactly $k$ fixed points, you could first choose the fixed points ($\binom nk$ possibilities) and then choose a [derangement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement) of the remaining $n-k$ elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your case-by-case approach is fine, but some of your reasoning is not.  For $k = 10$, the probability is substantially higher than $\frac{1}{10!}$.  This is because cards of the same color are indistinguishable.  So among the $10!$ orderings of $10$ cards, there are $7!$ permutations of the red cards amongst each other, and $3!$ permutations of the green cards amongst each other.  So for a given ordering of the cards, there are $7!3!$ ways to rearrange them that still look the same.  Since there is one essentially distinguishable arrangement in which all red and all green cards are put in matching envelopes, the resulting probability of this outcome is $$\frac{7!3!}{10!} = \frac{1}{\binom{10}{3}}.$$

For odd $k$, the probability is always $0$ because the only way a card is not matched to an envelope of the same color is if it has been switched with a card of the opposite color.  That is to say, the number of green cards put in red envelopes must always equal the number of red cards put into green envelopes.

This also says something about the maximum number of mismatches.  Since there are only $3$ green cards, the maximum number of mismatches is $6$, so the minimum number of matches is $4$.  So $\Pr[k\le 3] = 0$.

This leaves the cases $k \in \{4, 6, 8\}$, which you have correctly reasoned for the numerator, but the denominator is $\binom{10}{3}$ as in the case $k = 10$ I have described above.  You can see this must be true by observing that your probabilities do not add up to $1$, whereas with the correct denominator, we have

$$\frac{1}{\binom{10}{3}} + \frac{\binom{7}{6}\binom{3}{1}}{\binom{10}{3}} + \frac{\binom{7}{5}\binom{3}{2}}{\binom{10}{3}} + \frac{\binom{7}{4}\binom{3}{3}}{\binom{10}{3}} = 1.$$  This also suggests that the $k = 10$ case could be written as $$\frac{\binom{7}{7}\binom{3}{0}}{\binom{10}{3}}.$$  Can you generalize this result for $r$ red cards and envelopes, $g$ green cards and envelopes, and write an expression for $k = 2n$ matchings?  You may assume without loss of generality that $r \ge g$.

Comment: i did a mistake ,if you observe i said the number of simple space is ${10 \choose 3}$,but in each case i divided by $10!$,now it fixed.